# How to join up 2 list with a distinct format?

Tags: python, join, concatenation

how do I join these 2 list

```
suits = ['C','D','H','S']
```

and

```
value = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
```

to A-C, 2-C and so forth until K-S?

i tried doing these format but it didn't work

```
def options():
    i = 13
    option1 = []
    while True:
      option = input()
      suits = ['C','D','H','S']
      value = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
      cards = str
      _input = int(input())
      suit = suits[_input-1]
      for j in value:
       option1 = print(j+"-"+suit+",", end="")  
      return option1
```

Comment: `from itertools import product; list(map(lambda x: "-".join(x), product(value, suits)))`

Comment: What you call `value` is generally referred to as the *ranks* of the cards. So I would rename `value` to `ranks` and then: `deck = [f'{rank}-{suit}' for suit in suits for rank in ranks]`, which produces a list such as `['A-C', '2-C`, ... 'K-S']`.

Answer (score 0):

already answered it
i did this instead
'''suits = ['C','D','H','S']
value = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
for i in suits:
for j in value:
cards = print(j+"-"+i, end=",")'''